# Is there a risk to get infected from unmounted USB storage device

Tags: mount, security, usb, removable-storage

I want to format an USB device i suspect to be infected with virus/es to make it safe for use again using my linux machine.

If the device is never mounted is there still a risk of a virus or maleware of any time to be able to execute somehow and infect my machine?

Do you have any alternatives on how to safely cleaning the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to wipe it using a live USB with a distro of your choice. Just make sure you don't mount neither the infected thumb drive nor any of disks that you have on your machine.

As thumb drive is actually an empty system without any valuable data on it, there is nothing to corrupt. Also the live distro is loaded into your RAM that won't save any data when you power off your machine.

That's the way to go.

Comment: Of course it doesn't hurt to be extra careful, but as long as there's no automounter active, it's perfectly safe to just wipe USB storage devices using your usual system and `dd` (or whatever). And even with an automounter there'll probably no trouble, because unlike on Windows, Linux doesn't try to execute stuff on the stick by default. USB hardware acting as HID or other input devices is a different story, though.

Comment: This answers the "alternatives to cleaning the device" part, but it doesn't explicitly answer the main question ("can an unmounted USB stick on a Linux machine infect the system?"). If it's "better to use a live USB/CD" to do the job, am I right to infer that there is, indeed, some risk of such infection?

Comment: @Ratler It depends on a lot of factors. If we assume that the drive won't get mounted automatically as soon as it is plugged in, then I doubt there is a way to infect the host. But in reality, say, Ubuntu does auto mount external drives by default, which will definitely give whatever on a drive a chance to do something potentially malicious.

The most explicit and realistic answer to "can an unmounted USB stick on a Linux machine infect the system?" is "You never know". Paranoia is a virtue.